# TV screen not detected anymore

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, amd-graphics, totem

I have had a dual monitor (one tv, one monitor) setup for a few month on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. And I've had this setup before for a few years on xubuntu 14 and older.

Whenever I've watched some MP4 videos with Totem on Ubuntu 16 sometimes the screens started reconfiguring and sometimes one of the screens wasn't recognized anymore. This all reconfigured itself usually. However, this time the tv screen (LG32LC52) isn't detected anymore even if I restart the pc.

The tv screen is connected to HDMI-0. Unplugging and plugging the hdmi cable has no effect. I checked the hdmi cable and the tv screen on another pc device. They are working.

Additionally all videos played with Totem and Youtube now play in double speed, although normal speed is activated.

I rebooted the pc and switched to Kubuntu 14 and Win 7. No HDMI as well.
I replaced the graphic card with another one and still no HDMI. Might this be a motherboard issue?

```
xrandr --current
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       60.00
```

My graphics card:

```
lspci | grep VGA
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV730 PRO [Radeon HD 4650]
```

I used the hdmi port of my monitor - this works! So the monitor works via hdmi port, but only the tv is not, although the tv works on my notebook

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94
```

Funny how this states the VGA port is connected.

I freshly installed Ubuntu 16, but the problems persist.
I switched to the aforementioned other graphics card, which is the following:

```
lspci | grep VGA
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G86 [GeForce 8400 GS] (rev a1)
```

I turned on the nvidia-304 drivers (304.137) in the Applications & Updates -> Additional drivers section. I would have the option to switch to nvidia-340 (340.104) or Nouveau. Those do not recognize the tv at all though.

It recognizes the tv. But only as a vga device with a resolution of 800x600, although it is still connected via hdmi.

```
xrandr --current
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2720 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected primary 1920x1080+800+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       59.94  
VGA-0 connected 800x600+0+480 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   800x600       60.32*+
```

I have the feeling the Totem crash caused an EDID corruption and only Windows still can recognize the tv(?).

I still have my old 16.04 distribution aside. When I boot it, I can see the following message several times in the kern.log:

```
kernel: [  519.320215] nouveau 0000:05:00.0: DRM: DDC responded, but no EDID for VGA-1
```

I have no clue as to how to debug this behavior any further.

---

Update:
In the meantime I tried different TVs and different graphic cards (also a current one: Palit NE5105T018G1H).
With other TVs I have a video signal. With the new graphics card, I had a video signal as well, but not up to the highest resolution (720p) but only to 1280x*.

I am using another TV now and the video signal usually shows 1080p. However, the TV "randomly" loses its video signal. Turning it off and on again normally brings it back.

But sometimes individual web sites viewed via Firefox seem to crash the signal and the TV loses it. Turning it off and on again is of no help then. Closing the web site does help. Viewing the web site in Chrome for instance does give a more stable result, but not to 100%.